# Why does Java need cmd /c or cmd /k to execute multi-segment ADB

Tags: java, exec

I need to execute a multi-segment `adb` command in the java program with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. Take a screenshot and save it to my computer. As follows: [It succeeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBHJE.png)

But if I remove `cmd /c`, I will get an error. As follows: [It failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laeGT.png)

Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, when asking, don't post your code/errors/etc in image or image links. Instead, write it in the question, so others can quickly get to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because in your first case, you execute `cmd.exe` with arguments. `cmd.exe` knows how to handle `&&` - namely, executing the first `adb` command, then executing the second `adb` command.

In your second case, you are executing `adb` with arguments. `adb` doesn't understand `&&` as command separator - it tries to interpret it as an argument to itself and fails (`&&` is not a valid argument for `adb`)